# How to make MS Excel return error if the date is wrong

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

How to make the below formula return an error since 31/Feb/2023 is a wrong date.

[image]

Comment: What are you regional settings set to? Month first or Day first?

Comment: @braX Day first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(C2 & "-" & B2 & "-" & A2)),"not a valid date", DATE(C2,B2,A2))
```

`DATEVALUE` returns an error for e.g. 31/Feb/2023 but not for 28/Feb/2023.

I tested this on a German version ... with dd.MM.yyyy as default setting.

Comment: If I could suggest a slightly shorter version: `=IFERROR(DATEVALUE(C1&"-"&B1&"-"&A1),"not a valid date")`

Comment: That was my first idea as well - that will work if number format of cell is set to date